# Wireshark dissector with pcapng format file - access section/interface description fields

Tags: c, wireshark, wireshark-dissector

I am writing a custom protocol wireshark dissector in C as a plugin. I have got the dissector working . I am not able to figure out if there is a way to access the information we fill in section header / interface description header from our dissector? There seem to be tvbuff and packet_info passed , which dont have this information.

Is there a way to access these fields?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the answer from wireshark forum : https://ask.wireshark.org/questions/58090/wireshark-dissector-with-pcapng-format-file-access-sectioninterface-description-fields